# ASP.Net Core MVC With Multiple Angular 2 Applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am trying to prepare the structure for a project which I know will grow in complexity. I want to use ASP.Net Core MVC for the top level navigation. Within each of the main Views I want to place an Angular 2 Application.

I have started with this Yoman template to scaffold out a starting point [Angular 2 with ASP.Net Core Template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/). This built and ran well.

In the root of my project I want to have an `AngularApps` folder and within that a folder for each Angular App, say 'Scheduling', 'Utilities', 'Equipment'.

There are a couple problems I cannot understand:

1. How do I configure Webpack?
2. Do I have a single `dist` folder within `AngularApps`?
3. Do I have a `boot-client` and `boot-server` file for each Angular 2 application within its respective app folder?

It seems to me a pragmatic approach to plan from the beginning to have multiple Angular 2 applications, each with a more focussed responsibility. I cannot find any clear examples of how to practically make this work though. I'm sure this would be valuable for many people.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

We had the same issue at our company and came up with this structure.

We have one master project for ASP.NET Core, and like you... we have the root folder named apps or AngularApps in your case.  We then created separate projects for each angular app we developed.  Each of these Angular apps are basic node projects that we use Angular CLI to build to project.  This includes Webpack and a host of other great tools for your project.

Finally, in the Production build settings, we made our output directory of these angular projects set to a specific folder in the wwwroot folder of our master ASP.NET Core Project.

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: P.S. Angular CLI will help handle the configuration of your webpack files.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Both Angular and ASP.Net are new to me so I am grappling to understand how I can bring it all together. I like separation of concerns and a methodical structure to my work though. If you have multiple Projects, how do you configure so that you can debug please?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you have each Angular app in a separate VS Project, what is in your apps folder in the root?

Comment: Our wwwroot folder has sub folders within it, ie. Project1, Project2, etc.  The dist folders are published into these folders and the master ASP.NET Core Views are setup to launch each folder.  As for debugging you will need to do a little setup but it's well worth it.  Make sure you enable CORS in the master project and if you use Chrome to launch your client side code then use this to launch it.  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-web-security  --user-data-dir="C:\Users\-user-\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"

Comment: @aholtry Interesting idea. I see the Angular-Cli also supports multiple apps which is great. How do you handle the versioned assets that the angular-cli outputs. Do you use an inject plugin to add the versioned scripts/styles to your razor pages?